# Error en acceso a recursos desde servidor publico

Tags: linux, ssh, redes, ip, ubuntu-server

Tengo el siguiente problema, es un poco extraño.

Dispongo de un servidor con **Ubuntu Server 18**, el cual cuenta con una IP publica contratada con el ISP.

El servidor funciona correctamente desde la red externa al router, es decir, al acceder desde otra red que no sea la de la empresa, todo funciona correctamente, se puede acceder desde SSH, la pagina web, los repositorios, entre otros. Pero desde la red local no es posible acceder a dichos recursos, aunque el servidor responde el ping.

**64 bytes from 18X.1XX.XXX.XXX: icmp_seq=0 ttl=62 time=36.324 ms**

Al acceder por SSH, se genera el siguiente error, **Connection reset by 18X.1XX.XXX.XXX port 22** y en la traza del servidor, se puede ver el mismo error. Por otro lado, la pagina no carga correctamente, las bases de datos son inaccesibles, es decir, como si todo estuviera bloqueado.

Unicamente pasa cuando estoy conectado en la red local, de lo contrario todo funciona correctamente, ya valide el Netplan, con el ISP el Passthrough y esta correcto, el Firewall lo desactive por un momento, pero nada, no sé que puede ser.

**Nota: El servidor no esta por DMZ**

[image: error my sql]
[image: Error de gogs]
[image: Error SQL Server]

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas por una red interna, ¿le has añadido esa red interna al servidor?

Lo suyo seria que dentro de la LAN todas las conexiones sean por una `192.168.x.x` en vez de que salga fuera.

Ten en cuenta que para poder hacer eso tienes que tener configurado el servidor para que responda a IPs de la red LAN, tendrás que modificar:

- `firewalld` (en caso de que lo tengas): https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-open-allow-incoming-firewall-port-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux
- `Apache`: Deberías de tener algo así:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  xxx.com
    ServerAlias www.xxx.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx

    <Directory "/var/www/xxx">
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted

    </Directory>

    LogLevel notice
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/xxx.access.log" combined
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/xxx.error.log"
</VirtualHost>
```

Y si quieres poder conectarte a la base de datos con algun gestor tipo SqlYog o MySQLWorkBench también tendrás que modificar el servicio de MySQL:

Editar `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` y dentro de `[mysqld]` poner:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

El problema de esto es que quedaría abierto el puerto a todo internet. Lo mejor en ese caso es ponerlo a localhost y que quien se quiera conectar lo haga mediante un túnel SSH.

https://linube.com/ayuda/articulo/240/como-conectar-un-servidor-mysql-de-forma-remota

Revisa todo esto, lo mejor es que la IP pública solo se use fuera de la red y que dentro una una IP privada.

Si tienes dudas me comentas.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero el servidor tiene configuradas dos IP's publicas, cada una asociada a un Dominio, esto porque es un servidor de desarrollo, el cual es accedido por los desarrolladores desde Internet, pero yo que me encuentro en sitio, no puedo acceder a los recursos correctamente, lo curioso es que hace poco cambiaron el Router, después de eso, empezó a suceder esto, editare la pregunta para adjuntar mas información.

Comment: El error que parece ahí es de SSL. ¿Es un certificado válido? ¿Es un Let's Encrypt? ¿Es válido y está correctamente configurado?

Comment: No tiene SSL configurado, y como te digo, pasa unicamente en sitio, desde afuera no sale ningún error.